# Remove the last character in a string in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I remove the last character in a string in `T-SQL`?

For example:

```
'TEST STRING'
```

to return:

```
'TEST STRIN'
```

Answer (score 217):

e.g.

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(100)
SET @String = 'TEST STRING'

-- Chop off the end character
SET @String = 
     CASE @String WHEN null THEN null 
     ELSE (
         CASE LEN(@String) WHEN 0 THEN @String 
            ELSE LEFT(@String, LEN(@String) - 1) 
         END 
     ) END


SELECT @String
```

Comment: Alternatively: 
SELECT LEFT(YourColumnName, LEN(YourColumnName) - 1) FROM YourTable

Comment: Thanks for the null catch - ISNULL(LEFT(@String, LEN(@String) - 1),'ErrMsg') will solve

Comment: @Volvox it will still throw exception if the string is Empty String, i am modifying your answer to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 131):

If for some reason your column logic is complex (case when ... then ... else ... end), then the above solutions causes you to have to repeat the same logic in the len() function.  Duplicating the same logic becomes a mess.  If this is the case then this is a solution worth noting.  This example gets rid of the last unwanted comma.  I finally found a use for the REVERSE function.

```
select reverse(stuff(reverse('a,b,c,d,'), 1, 1, ''))
```

Comment: Note that this code returns `NULL` if passed a string that is shorter than the delete range specified for `STUFF`.  Wrap it in an `ISNULL` to get a different output value for the empty string case.

Comment: Nice, using this with an outer apply, with a for xml path('') to eliminate a trailing comma.  awseome

Comment: Also the same way as @Tracker1. Unlike anything involving LEN() this gracefully works (without repeating anything) for empty string (especially wrapped in ISNULL())

Comment: Thanks, it helped me, in my case i had a last space so the first index is 2 `select reverse(stuff(reverse('a,b,c,d,'), 2, 1, ''))`

Answer (score 83):

Try this:

```
select substring('test string', 1, len('test string') - 1)
```

Comment: @Adrien any idea why this seems to give the same result as `select substring('test string', 0, len('test string'))`?

Comment: @Louis, the substring syntax is as follows: `SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , length )`. Now, both queries return the same because the numbering is 1 based, meaning that the first character in the expression is 1. If start is less than 1, the returned expression will begin at the first character that is specified in expression. [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Worked nicely in removing last 4 characters by changing the last part to `- 4))`

Answer (score 33):

If your string is empty,

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(100)
SET @String = ''
SELECT LEFT(@String, LEN(@String) - 1)
```

then this code will cause error message 'Invalid length parameter passed to the substring function.'

You can handle it this way:

```
SELECT LEFT(@String, NULLIF(LEN(@String)-1,-1))
```

It will always return result, and NULL in case of empty string.

Answer (score 29):

This will work even when source text/var is null or empty:

```
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@a), 2, 9999))
```

Comment: This is an Underrated comment, it's fast and it doesn't have to select the string twice to work.

Answer (score 14):

```
select left('TEST STRING', len('TEST STRING')-1)
```

Answer (score 13):

This is quite late, but interestingly never mentioned yet.

```
select stuff(x,len(x),1,'')
```

ie:

```
take a string x
go to its last character
remove one character
add nothing
```

Answer (score 11):

```
@result = substring(@result, 1, (LEN(@result)-1))
```

Answer (score 7):

If your coloumn is `text` and not `varchar`, then you can use this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@String, 1, NULLIF(DATALENGTH(@String)-1,-1))
```

Comment: Also, `LEN` trims trailing spaces, while `DATALENGTH` doesn't.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to do this in two steps, rather than the three of REVERSE-STUFF-REVERSE, you can have your list separator be one or two spaces. Then use RTRIM to trim the trailing spaces, and REPLACE to replace the double spaces with ','

```
select REPLACE(RTRIM('a  b  c  d  '),'  ', ', ')
```

However, this is not a good idea if your original string can contain internal spaces.

Not sure about performance. Each REVERSE creates a new copy of the string, but STUFF is a third faster than REPLACE.

also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333613/fastest-way-to-update-varchar-column-with-text)

Answer (score 5):

I can suggest this -hack- ;).

```
select 
    left(txt, abs(len(txt + ',') - 2))
from 
    t;
```

[**SQL Server Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/702)

Answer (score 3):

you can create function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[TRUNCRIGHT] (@string NVARCHAR(max), @len int = 1)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(max)
AS
BEGIN
    IF LEN(@string)<@len
        RETURN ''
    RETURN LEFT(@string, LEN(@string) - @len)
END
```

Answer (score 2):

Get the last character

```
Right(@string, len(@String) - (len(@String) - 1))
```

Comment: I don't think this is what he was asking, though -- this might be useful to put in a comment, however.

Comment: just Right(@string, 1).

Answer (score 1):

My answer is similar to the accepted answer, but it also check for Null and Empty String.

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(100)

SET @String = 'asdfsdf1'

-- If string is null return null, else if string is empty return as it is, else chop off the end character
SET @String = Case @String when null then null else (case LEN(@String) when 0 then @String else LEFT(@String, LEN(@String) - 1) end ) end

SELECT @String
```

Answer (score 1):

To update the record by trimming the last N characters of a particular column:

```
UPDATE tablename SET columnName = LEFT(columnName , LEN(columnName )-N) where clause
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(100)
SET @String = 'TEST STRING'
SELECT LEFT(@String, LEN(@String) - 1) AS MyTrimmedColumn
```

Comment: How is this different from the [answer posted four years prior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10363621/11683)?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem and this way my problem was solved:

```html
Declare @name as varchar(30)='TEST STRING'  
Select left(@name, len(@name)-1) as AfterRemoveLastCharacter
```

Comment: How is this different from the [answer posted ten years prior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10363621/11683)?

Answer (score 0):

I love @bill-hoenig 's answer; however, I was using a subquery and I got caught up because the REVERSE function needed two sets of parentheses.  Took me a while to figure that one out!

```
SELECT
   -- Return comma delimited list of all payment reasons for this Visit
   REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE((
        SELECT DISTINCT
               CAST(CONVERT(varchar, r1.CodeID) + ' - ' + c.Name + ', ' AS VARCHAR(MAX))
          FROM VisitReason r1
          LEFT JOIN ReasonCode c        ON c.ID = r1.ReasonCodeID
         WHERE p.ID = r1.PaymentID
         FOR XML PATH('')
              )), 1, 2, ''))                        ReasonCode
  FROM Payments p
```

Comment: You may want to use an outer/cross apply for the composite portion of the query.  I'm using this to get a set of flags for a parent item.

Answer (score 0):

Try It :

```
  DECLARE @String NVARCHAR(100)
    SET @String = '12354851'
    SELECT LEFT(@String, NULLIF(LEN(@String)-1,-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @string varchar(20)= 'TEST STRING'
Select left(@string, len(@string)-1) as Tada
```

output:

```
Tada
--------------------
TEST STRIN
```

Comment: How is this different from the [answer posted three years prior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10363621/11683)?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, if your string `@s` is of a certain max size, say 10 characters.

`select trim(substring(right(replicate(' ', 10) + coalesce(@s,''), 10), 1, 9))`

This approach was useful when converting GTIN numbers (10 - 14 digits with a final check digit and leading 0s) to a UPC with no check digit or leading 0s:

`cast(cast(SUBSTRING(RIGHT('00000' + @gtin, 14), 1, 13) as bigint) as varchar)`

Examples:

- 0012345235 --> 1234523
- 12345678901234 --> 1234567890123

Answer (score 0):

```sql
declare @string varchar(1000) = null
select @string =  isnull(substring (@string, 1, nullif(len(@string)-1,-1)), '')
select @string 
go

declare @string varchar(1000) = ''
select @string =  isnull(substring (@string, 1, nullif(len(@string)-1,-1)), '')
select @string 
go

declare @string varchar(1000) = '123,'
select @string =  isnull(substring (@string, 1, nullif(len(@string)-1,-1)), '')
select @string
```

Comment: I guess your English is not very good since all your answers essentially contain only code. That's why they are getting down-voted. Maybe [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/) can help you translate your explanations from your native Korean to English? (Maybe it can help to translate this comment, also.)

Comment: Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and why it helps to solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
declare @x varchar(20),@y varchar(20)
select @x='sam'
select 
case when @x is null then @y
      when @y is null then @x
      else @x+','+@y
end


go

declare @x varchar(20),@y varchar(20)
select @x='sam'
--,@y='john'
DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)   

SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@x + ', ' ,'') +coalesce(@y+',','')
SELECT left(@listStr,len(@listStr)-1)
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this,

```
DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(MAX) SET @name='xxxxTHAMIZHMANI****'SELECT Substring(@name, 5, (len(@name)-8)) as UserNames
```

And the output will be like, THAMIZHMANI