# fastest way to update varchar column with text

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, string

I have the following in a column:

```
MetaDataServe
-------------
MindWorks.Accounts
MindWorks.Transactions
MindWorks.Commissions
...
```

I need to update those columns to be in the form of:

```
MindWorks.Client.Accounts
```

I initially thought of using the string functions to update them (LEFT, SUBSTR etc), but is there an alternative or better method of updating text in a column to insert text?

I am using SQL Server 2008 and can't use CLR integration.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a question about "fastest", so timings are provided below

### Test setup, table with >1 million rows

```
create table MetaDataServe (id int identity primary key, vc varchar(max));

insert MetaDataServe values
('MindWorks.Accounts'),
('MindWorks.Transactions'),
('MindWorks.Commissions');

insert MetaDataServe
select vc
from MetaDataServe, master..spt_values a, master..spt_values b
where b.number between 1 and 30
-- (1090110 row(s) affected)
```

### Stuff vs Replace vs SubString

**Performance Summary - STUFF > SUBSTRING > REPLACE**

```
update MetaDataServe set vc = STUFF(vc, 9, 0, '.Client')
```

> SQL Server parse and compile time: 
> CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 3 ms.
> Table 'MetaDataServe'. Scan count 1, logical reads 55402, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:
> CPU time = 10094 ms,  elapsed time = 10808 ms.
> CPU time = 10250 ms,  elapsed time = 10896 ms.

*(the 2 times are from multiple executions to show the variability, it is quite low so the times can be considered accurate to within 3%)*

```
update MetaDataServe set vc = REPLACE(vc, '.', '.Client.')
```

> SQL Server parse and compile time: 
> CPU time = 3 ms, elapsed time = 3 ms.
> Table 'MetaDataServe'. Scan count 1, logical reads 55402, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 159, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:
> CPU time = 20469 ms,  elapsed time = 21238 ms.

```
update MetaDataServe set vc = 'MindWorks.Client.' + SUBSTRING(vc, 11, 100)
```

> SQL Server parse and compile time: 
> CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 1 ms.
> Table 'MetaDataServe'. Scan count 1, logical reads 55402, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 3, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:
> CPU time = 11219 ms,  elapsed time = 12030 ms.
> CPU time = 11531 ms,  elapsed time = 12148 ms.

### Fixed number vs PATINDEX vs CHARINDEX

*(The fixed position version is already given above)*
**Performance Summary - FIXED > (PATINDEX = CHARINDEX)**
<sub><sup>There appears to be no material difference between PATINDEX and CHARINDEX</sup></sub>

```
update MetaDataServe set vc = STUFF(vc, PATINDEX('%.%',vc), 0, '.Client')
```

> SQL Server parse and compile time: 
> CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 2 ms.
> Table 'MetaDataServe'. Scan count 1, logical reads 55400, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:
> CPU time = 15218 ms,  elapsed time = 16167 ms.

```
update MetaDataServe set vc = STUFF(vc, CHARINDEX('.',vc), 0, '.Client')
```

> SQL Server parse and compile time: 
> CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 3 ms.
> Table 'MetaDataServe'. Scan count 1, logical reads 55402, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:
> CPU time = 15469 ms,  elapsed time = 16353 ms.

#### Notes:

- All update statements given above will work (with a tweak or two) depending on your needs
- Before each test, the entire table is dropped and recreated to prevent caching issues

#### CAUTION !

Even though STUFF is faster, you can get into tricky situations.  If your data contains

```
"MindWorksNoDot"
```

And you update using

```
update MetaDataServe set vc = STUFF(vc, CHARINDEX('.',vc), 0, '.Client')
```

You end up with NULL! Because when CHARINDEX cannot find the dot, the second parameter to STUFF of zero (0) causes the entire string to go to **NULL**.

#### FINAL WORDS

For safety and reliability, given it is only 33% slower than the STUFF approach, I would simply use a REPLACE statement, i.e.

```
update MetaDataServe set vc = REPLACE(vc, '.', '.Client.')
```

Answer (score 3):

### Using the [STUFF command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx):

```
WITH sample AS (
  SELECT 'MindWorks.Accounts' AS col
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'MindWorks.Transactions'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'MindWorks.Commissions')
SELECT s.col,
       STUFF(s.col, CHARINDEX('.', s.col), 1, '.Client.') AS col2
  FROM sample s
```

### Using the [REPLACE command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx):

```
WITH sample AS (
  SELECT 'MindWorks.Accounts' AS col
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'MindWorks.Transactions'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'MindWorks.Commissions')
SELECT s.col,
       REPLACE(s.col, '.', '.Client.') AS col2
  FROM sample s
```

### Output:

```
col                      col2
--------------------------------------------------------
MindWorks.Accounts       MindWorks.Client.Accounts
MindWorks.Transactions   MindWorks.Client.Transactions
MindWorks.Commissions    MindWorks.Client.Commissions
```

### Conclusion

Of the two, STUFF is likely to be more flexible.  Just depends on your needs.