# SQL Alpha Numeric sorting issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, natural-sort

I have found that we could sort a column in table even if it is alpha numeric.

The only problem here I have is if the column data is only characters it throws error.

```
BEGIN TRAN

USE SomeDatabase
CREATE TABLE dbo.Section
(
       Section varchar(50) NULL
)
INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('BB')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('1 ')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('AB 1')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('A21')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('B2')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('A11')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('B20')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('B21')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('AB10')
INSERT INTO dbo.Section (Section.Section) VALUES ('A10')
SELECT Section
FROM dbo.Section

SELECT Section
FROM dbo.Section
ORDER BY LEFT(Section,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Section)-1), -- alphabetical sort
         CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(Section,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Section),LEN(Section))) -- numerical sort

DROP Table dbo.Section

ROLLBACK
```

So, sorting 'BB' is the problem. If you remove BB then it all works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious problem from looking at your code, is that the `PATINDEX` will return 0 if it doesn't find anything. Because you then have `0 - 1` as a length, the LEFT function will throw an error.

Try this instead:

```
...
ORDER BY LEFT(Section
             ,CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Section) >= 2
                   THEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Section) - 1
                   ELSE LEN(Section)
                   END
             ), -- alphabetical sort
     CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Section) >= 1
          THEN CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(Section,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Section),LEN(Section) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Section) - 1))
          END -- numerical sort
...
```

Comment: try the latest edit, I saw a second bug, where you weren't subtracting the PATINDEX() value from the Length of the SUBSTRING function ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the Patindex is returning 0 in both order by clause. I corrected it below.

```
declare  @Section TABLE
(
       Section varchar(50) NULL
)
INSERT INTO @Section (Section) VALUES ('BB')
INSERT INTO @Section (Section) VALUES ('1 ')
INSERT INTO @Section (Section) VALUES ('AB 1')
INSERT INTO @Section (Section) VALUES ('A21')
INSERT INTO @Section (Section) VALUES ('B2')
INSERT INTO @Section (Section) VALUES ('A11')
INSERT INTO @Section (Section) VALUES ('B20')
INSERT INTO @Section (Section) VALUES ('B21')
INSERT INTO @Section (Section) VALUES ('AB10')
INSERT INTO @Section (Section) VALUES ('A10')
SELECT Section
FROM @Section

SELECT Section
FROM @Section

ORDER BY Section
--LEFT(Section,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Section)-1), -- alphabetical sort
--         CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(Section,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Section),LEN(Section))) -- numerical sort



SELECT Section  
FROM @Section
ORDER BY LEFT(Section,case when PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Section) < 1 then 1 else PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Section) end -1), -- alphabetical sort
         case when PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Section) < 1 then 0 else CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(Section,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Section),LEN(Section))) end -- numerical sort


Section
--------------------------------------------------
BB
1 
AB 1
A21
B2
A11
B20
B21
AB10
A10


Section
--------------------------------------------------
BB
1 
A10
A11
A21
AB 1
AB10
B2
B20
B21
```

Comment: This does not sort.. defeats the purpose.

Comment: Please add the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stuff()` instead of `substring()` like so:

```
select section
  , alpha = left(section,patindex('%[0-9]%',section+'0')-1)
  , num   = stuff(section,1,patindex('%[0-9]%',section)-1,'')
from section
order by 
    left(section,patindex('%[0-9]%',section+'0')-1)
  , convert(int,stuff(section,1,patindex('%[0-9]%',section)-1,''))
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/JOXUEE9700

output:

```
+---------+-------+------+
| section | alpha | num  |
+---------+-------+------+
| 1       |       | 1    |
| A10     | A     | 10   |
| A11     | A     | 11   |
| A21     | A     | 21   |
| AB 1    | AB    | 1    |
| AB10    | AB    | 10   |
| B2      | B     | 2    |
| B20     | B     | 20   |
| B21     | B     | 21   |
| BB      | BB    | NULL |
+---------+-------+------+
```

Comment: Excellent alternative. Thanks much. Do you think performance wise which one is better?

Comment: @Doctor I'd say they are probably the same, if you want to see the performance difference over 1 million rows you can check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5334093/2333499 which shows `stuff()` as being faster than `substring()` but your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thanks I try @ but I don't get your name for whatever reason.