# Remove last character from string column in SQL Server CE

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-ce

In SQL Server Compact, I'm trying to remove a trailing comma that came from a goof which affected several thousand rows of a `NVARCHAR` column.

```
UPDATE myTable 
SET col = LEFT(col, LEN(col)-1) 
WHERE col LIKE '%,';
```

throws the error:

> *There was an error parsing the query. [ Token in error = LEFT ]*

Can SQL Server CE not parse that query? Or, can someone offer another approach?

Note: I tried this in [CompactView](http://sourceforge.net/projects/compactview/), I'm not sure if that's the problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Based off [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1256924/434034) I was able to get it done using [SUBSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx):

```
UPDATE myTable
SET col = SUBSTRING(col, 0, LEN(col))
WHERE col LIKE '%,';
```

Comment: I have tried this but was not worked, I have used `LEFT( col, LENGTH( col ) -1 )`

Answer (score 1):

The proposed solution with using `SET col = SUBSTRING(col, 0, LEN(col))` is a bit unclear.

This is working as a side effect of the SUBSTRING second parameter starting_position being "1 based". So 0 in this case is kind of negative (you could also use i.e. -3 and 4 characters would be stripped then instead of 1).
IMHO it would be much more clear to use this:

`UPDATE myTable
SET col = SUBSTRING(col, 1, LEN(col)-1)
WHERE col LIKE '%,';`

Which shows the code's intent

Answer (score 0):

```
    UPDATE myTable
    SET col = SUBSTR(col, 0, (LENGTH(col) - 1))
    WHERE col LIKE '%,';
```