# How to append data to a JSON object during a select?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, database-migration

I'm in the progress of migrating data from an old system. I have some boolean columns, which can be `True`, `False` or `Null`. Each column has a certain meaning. In the new database, I use a JSON Data object. What I would like to achieve is this:

```
OldTable:
ValueA, ValueB, ValueC, ValueD
Null  , True  , False , True
```

I create now Json data using a select on my old table and `FOR JSON` to get the Json object. The object should look something like this:

```
{
     myObject: {
           data: "valueB, ValueD"
     }
}
```

My problem is the appending the values to the same "data" field.

So right now I can only do it with single values like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ValueA == True THEN 'ValueA' END 'myObject.data',
       CASE WHEN ValueB == True THEN 'ValueB' END 'myObject.data'  
FROM myLegacyTable FOR JSON Path
```

This would obviously overwrite, what ever is in `myObject.data`, whenever both values are true. `JSON_MODIFY` seems not to be an option, as I'm not working on an existing Json object, but creating a new one. Maybe someone else has an idea?

Comment: Your expected result is not a valid json expression. You probably want a json array instead: `{ "myObject": { "data": ["valueB", "ValueD"] } }`

Comment: Hi Andrea, thank you for the comment. I update my post. I don't want an json array, but one json value, which is a comma seperated list. I use this to set a .net Flag Enum.

Comment: `==` is not valid T-SQL syntax and neither is `True`. Even though we understand your meaning, this whole thing works better when you post functioning code. What exactly is in `myLegacyTable`?

Comment: JSON is a good message format but not a good choice to store relational data. You make it even worse by then breaking the rules of JSON by stuffing multiple attributes into one property.... Anyway the value of `data` in your JSON is just a string. So just generate that entire string inside _one_ column with a select statement. Don't put it in seperate columns because your JSON is just referring to one single string.

Comment: What is the expected output when the table contains more than one row?

Comment: Hi @Nick, thank you for your concern, but I'm quite sure about the way I'm handling this. The example is also just ment for clarification. It is not meant to be a working example.

Comment: @Andrea: The JSON structure is not repeating. There is only one JSON object in a data column. The next row will produce a new output row. For the purpose of clarity, assume there is only one row.

Comment: Ok, thank you: I was waiting for your reply to post my answer, have a look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just build your json string with a `CASE WHEN`. If you want to handle a variable  number of columns you'll probably need dynamic TSQL.

This is a simple static version that should do the job:

```
declare @tmp table(ValueA bit, ValueB bit, ValueC bit, ValueD bit)
insert into @tmp values (null, 1 ,0 , 1)

SELECT JSON_QUERY('{"data":"' + 
stuff(
      case when ValueA = 1 then  ',ValueA'  else '' end 
    + case when ValueB = 1 then  ',ValueB'  else '' end 
    + case when ValueC = 1 then  ',ValueC'  else '' end 
    + case when ValueD = 1 then  ',ValueD'  else '' end 
    ,1,1,'') 
    + '"}') as myObject
FROM @tmp FOR JSON Path, without_array_wrapper
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Andrea, that was the ticket! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your source data is really stored but here is an example of what you need to do if this was all in SQL Server

`data.property` is not seperate items so don't split it into columns. It's just a single concatenated string. So concatenate everything up and remove the trailing comma.

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (
RowID INT,
ValueA VARCHAR(5),
ValueB VARCHAR(5),
ValueC VARCHAR(5),
ValueD VARCHAR(5)
)

INSERT INTO @MyTable (RowID,ValueA,ValueB,ValueC,ValueD) VALUES 
(1,NULL,'True','False','True'),
(2,'False',NULL,'True','True'),
(3,NULL,'False',NULL,NULL)

SELECT 
ISNULL(
RTRIM(REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE
(
CASE WHEN ValueA='True' THEN 'ValueA, ' ELSE '' END +
CASE WHEN ValueB='True' THEN 'ValueB, ' ELSE '' END +
CASE WHEN ValueC='True' THEN 'ValueC, ' ELSE '' END +
CASE WHEN ValueD='True' THEN 'ValueD, ' ELSE '' END
), 2, 1, ''))),'') AS 'myObject.data'
FROM @MyTable
FOR JSON Path
```

The huge construct required to remove trailing `,` is from here:

[Remove the last character in a string in T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256915/remove-the-last-character-in-a-string-in-t-sql)

Result:

```
[
    {
        "myObject": {
            "data": "ValueB, ValueD"
        }
    },
    {
        "myObject": {
            "data": "ValueC, ValueD"
        }
    },
    {
        "myObject": {
            "data": ""
        }
    }
]
```